# Google maps, marker info is not close to his marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the lastest version of google maps, and trying to print the `markers` in the `map`.
To do that, I'm using:

```
function initmap2() {
        map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-scan'), {
            zoom: 16,
            styles: style,
            center: { lat: 13.7218501, lng: -89.2039192 }
        });

        for (i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
            markers = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(positions[i]),
                map: map2
            });
        }

        var markers = positions.map(function (location, i) {
            return new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
            });
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            markers[i].info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: '<b>' + positions[i]["title"].toUpperCase() + '</b>'
            });
            markers[i].info.open(map2, markers[i]);
        }

    }
```

The markers are displayed in the right position, but the `InfoWindws` are very distanced of them.

Why I'm using `map2` instead of `map`. I have preloaded another `googlemap` and the `map2` is loaded in a dialog (on demand, when the dialog is open)

How to fix this behavior?

[image]

Comment: it looks to me like you're setting `markers` twice. Once globally, but overwritting it each time, and once locally, but not setting it to the `map`. If you create a jsfiddle I can show you what I mean if not clear.

Comment: Without a working example, your markers ARRAY is never updated in the code you provided. I'd suggest changing variable names to increase readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this... you loop over `positions`, creating a marker for each of your positions:

```
    for (i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
        markers = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(positions[i]),
            map: map2
        });
    }
```

You then do the same thing again:

```
    var markers = positions.map(function (location, i) {
        return new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
        });
    });
```

And at the end of this 2nd way of doing it, `markers` is an array of markers.  Which you then loop over to setup the infowindows.

However, the first time you created the marker, you specified the `map` attribute.  So those markers show up on the map.
The second time you didn't bother, so these markers aren't on the map.

You've got markers visible thanks to your first way of doing it.  But then you're attaching the infowindows to the non-visible markers created the second way! :-/

The code's a bit of a mess, you can do it all in just the one loop over `positions`, and make sure you specify the `map` property for each marker.  I'd just do:

```
var markers = [];

for (i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(positions[i]),
        map: map2
    }));

    markers[i].info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: '<b>' + positions[i]["title"].toUpperCase() + '</b>'
    });
    markers[i].info.open(map2, markers[i]);
}
```